# How to convert map's keys from int to String in Flutter

Tags: dictionary, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a List of objects (this is an example of how the list would be filled by the user):

```
  List<Exercise> entreno = [
    Exercise(
      nombreEjercicio: 'Press Banca',
      serieData: [
        Serie(
          peso: '80',
          repes: '8',
        ),
        Serie(
          peso: '90',
          repes: '6',
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ];

class Exercise {
  String nombreEjercicio;
  List<Serie> serieData;

  Exercise({this.serieData, this.nombreEjercicio});
}

class Serie {
  String peso;
  String repes;
  String numSerie;

  Serie({this.peso, this.repes, this.numSerie});
}
```

The thing is that I want to pass this `List<Exercise> entreno` to firestore as the `setData()`, so I created a function to change the `List<Exercise>` type to `Map<String, dynamic>`:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> entrenamientoToMap(List<Exercise> entreno) {
    return Map.fromIterable(
      entreno,
      key: (e) => e.nombreEjercicio,
      value: (e) {
        return [
          for (var n in e.serieData) {'repeticiones': n.repes, 'peso': n.peso}
        ].asMap();
      },
    );
  }
```

With that I get something like this:

```
{Press Banca: {0: {repeticiones: 8, peso: 80}, 1: {repeticiones: 6, peso: 90}}}
```

and this is just what I want to upload to firestore.

But I'm getting this error when trying to set this as the `setData()`:

```
E/flutter (30304): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

I guess **the problem is on** `asMap()` because it gives int keys. Then, how can I convert map's keys from int to String so I can pass the data to firestore?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `.asMap()` function returns `Map<int, String>` that is where your code crashes.

You can add one `.forEach()` right after getting the Map from `.asMap()` function which can convert the keys and store it as `Map<String, String>`.

Have a look at this code snippet:

```
  List<String> items = ["one", "two", "three"];
  Map<int, String> basicMap = items.asMap(); //keys as int
  Map<String, String> newMap = new Map<String, String>(); //keys as String

  basicMap.forEach((key, value) {
    newMap.putIfAbsent(key.toString(), () => value);
  });
```

We can check that the keys are of type String using following loop:

```
  newMap.forEach((key, value){
    print(key is String);
  }); //prints true for all keys
```